# Does Integer addition takes constant amount of time for both small and big values in a program?

Tags: java, c

In Integer addtion even for small number, will computer scan each bit from 1st to 31st bit?

Comment: The computer doesn't scan anything; it has dedicated hardware that performs integer addition in a single cycle.

Comment: Huh, 31-bit computing?)

Comment: the actual number of instructions executed, and therefore the total execution time will depend on a few factors.  such as 1) are one or both of the values on the stack?  2) are one or both of the values in global memory? 3) is the number to be added small enough that the compiler will embed the number in the instruction?  4) is one or both of the numbers already available in the cache?  (if so, which cache)  The actual addition will (in modern CPUs be a single instruction, however the acquiring of the numbers and the storing of the result can be very different, time wise

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk I mentioned 31-bit because last bit will be sign bit.

Comment: The sign bit also has to be added.

Comment: Signed or unsigned: two's complement doesn't care.

Comment: @harold I agree with laune: on two's complement architectures it don't really matters.

Answer (score 1):

It depends by hardware... performing basic arithmetic operations on basic data types (eg. 32bit sum over a 32 bit hardware) need the same amount of time because there is a dedicated harware that perform operations.

On an ideal situation (on 32 bit architectures) 0+0 or 32767+32768 should take the same amount of time.

(By the way, if you implement a sum with custom code... - eg scanning every bit -- it is different)

Comment: ok. Thanks. I was confused when I saw one comment that on large int value, fibonacci number program will not be linear time anymore as addition will take more time.

Comment: @AdityaGoel This may have been written with "BigInteger" in mind, where numbers aren't represented by 32 bit but (long) arrays of digits of some base. With such numbers, addition time does increase with the size (number of digits) of the number.

Comment: @laune Thanks for your input but the comment was very specific about 32-bit integer only not some array.

Comment: @AdityaGoel Well, what was the comment? If it was referring to 32 bit integers it wasn't very clever - if it was to integers with arbitrary precision, it was.

Comment: @laune here is the comment https://disqus.com/home/discussion/geeksforgeeks/program_for_fibonacci_numbers/#comment-1378408411

Comment: The comment is pretty much wrong; essentially all hardware these days will implement "adding 4-bit numbers" by using the hardware to add 32-bit numbers.

Comment: I agree with Louis - I've never heard about an adder testing bits to stop adding prematurely. (BTW, if you have arbitrary precision, the complexity increases with O(log N).)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't understand why my comment is wrong... I spoked about "ideal" hardware situation... but I said that in the real case wumming two integers requires the same time (independently by the values you are summing)...

Comment: @laune I just said the same of you... and for Integer type (as asked) there are no time difference...

Answer (score 1):

There's some variation in propagation delays depending on the hardware implementation for an add, but for almost all processors, the number of cycles is fixed and based on the worst case possible propagation delay for the particular implementation. Link to example of one type of an optimized hardware adder:

[Kogge Stone adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kogge%E2%80%93Stone_adder)